# Can I use boot camp to install windows if I already have two versions of macOS?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro with a 1TB SSD, it currently has two APFS volumes one I boot into for high Sierra (for when I need to use legacy software) and my normal one for Catalina.

Is it still possible to use the boot camp utility to install and boot into windows or is that not a good idea? There’s plenty of information about dual boot and dual operating systems but I just wanted some clarification before I go and ruin my machine and have to wipe it and restore everything

Thanks for your time and consideration any help is much appreciated

output of diskutil list

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both the High Sierra and Catalina volumes in the same APFS container, then you should not have any problems using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows. You probably should have posted the output from the command `diskutil list`, so others could see if there might be some other issues regarding installing Windows.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think they are in the same container but I'm not sure, I have to admit I just followed a tutorial on how to get the two operating systems on there in the first place...I  just added a screenshot of the diskutil list output to my question if you can look at it, thanks again

Comment: Both the High Sierra and Catalina volumes are in the same APFS container. The Boot Camp Assistant will shrink `disk0s2` and create `disk0s3` in the free space. Windows will be installed in `disk0s3`.

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much! It worked just like you said it would now I have all three Operating Systems I need, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I have heard of triple booting and people succeeding, so I don't think it will be a problem if you install windows and have 2 versions already. Just make sure to choose the correct partitions when using Bootcamp and setting up windows.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping that was the case I just didn't know if there was something I was totally unaware that would turn my machine into a dumpster fire...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with your data on your internal storage then you could always go buy an SSD and Drive enclosure and install windows to that.

I used my windows computer to create a USB to go drive using a usb creator tool called Rufus and checked the Windows To Go option and Use External drives options and the result is that I have an external drive with windows on it that can be used on most new computers.

You could also just install windows directly to your drive without windows to go but you do run the risk that windows will install it's boot files to the EFI folder on your internal drive so I would recommend using Windows to go.

Comment: thanks that's an interesting solution, I may do that actually so you can just have a portable windows in your bag whenever you need it, I like that idea